# Code generation tools for crm 4.0

Tags: code-generation, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

Is there any free code generating tool that can connect to crm server and create code for selected entities? The code should use SDK assemblies.

**UPDATE:**
@friism
C# code if possible, each entity one class and each attribute one property so it's not necessary to use Properties collection. That's basically what I had in mind, when I started searching, but perhaps there is better solution out there.

Comment: Could you specify what code you want generated?

Comment: I've written a blog post with some sample code for talking with the metadata-service and generating classes: [http://friism.com/crmmetal-and-linqtocrm](http://friism.com/crmmetal-and-linqtocrm)

Comment: Yes, why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposedly this [MSCRM Developer Toolkit](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/E2DevTkt) contains a code generation feature.  I haven't used it.  I tried installing - but I had some installation issues.  Maybe you'll have more luck.

Answer (score 1):

We have a library called XrmLinq, it does exactly what LINQ to SQL does, generates classes by looking at the entities in crm. Take a look http://www.xrmlinq.com

Comment: Amanda, it appears that the site is down for some time now. Is there a way to get XrmLinq through some other means? Do you intend to open-source it so that your work on XrmLinq is not gone?

Answer (score 0):

The MSCRM Developer Toolkit contains a code generation feature. AND it's a huge pain to install.

Answer (score 0):

The CRM SDK (4.0.0012) now includes a free code-gen tool and LINQ query provider.

Shan